# Why does it keep reprinting the menu prompt followed by, monitor statement. I need it to restart and run through again until the use enters exit.

Tags: java

Sorry... I asked the wrong question..... I fixed my code a little. When I am using the while statement, I understand to use continue, however it will reprint the main menu prompt, but it also reprints the Monitor statement. Here is the updated code.
P.S. Not looking for an answer really...just some guidance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inFS = null;
    FileInputStream animals = null;
    FileInputStream habitats = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String monitorChoice = "";
    String animalChoice = "";
    String habitatChoice = "";
    String userInput = "";



    System.out.println("Would you like to monitor an Animal, Habitat, or exit?");
    monitorChoice = scnr.nextLine();

while (!userInput.equals("exit")){
        if (monitorChoice.equals("Animal")) {
            System.out.println("Choose an animal to monitor: Lion, Tiger, Bear, or Giraffe.");
            animals = new FileInputStream("animals.txt");
            animalChoice = scnr.nextLine();
            File file = new File("animals.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String currentLine = br.readLine();
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentLine.contains(animalChoice)) {
                    String nameline = br.readLine();
                    String ageline = br.readLine();
                    String healthline = br.readLine();
                    String feedline = br.readLine();

                    healthline = healthline.replaceAll("[*]", "");
                    feedline = feedline.replaceAll("[*]", "");

                    System.out.println(currentLine);
                    System.out.println(nameline);
                    System.out.println(ageline);
                    System.out.println(feedline);
                    System.out.println(healthline);

                    System.out.println("Would you like to monitor an Animal, Habitat, or exit");
      }
   }
}



        else if (monitorChoice.equals("Habitat")) {
            System.out.println("Choose a habitat to monitor: Penguin, Bird, Aquarium.");
            habitats = new FileInputStream("habitats.txt");
            habitatChoice = scnr.nextLine();
            File habitat = new File("habitats.txt");
            BufferedReader bh = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(habitat));

            String habitatLine = bh.readLine();
            while ((habitatLine = bh.readLine()) != null) {
                if (habitatLine.contains(habitatChoice)) {
                    String tempLine = bh.readLine();
                    String foodLine = bh.readLine();
                    String cleanLine = bh.readLine();

                    foodLine = foodLine.replaceAll("[*]", "");
                    cleanLine = cleanLine.replaceAll("[*]", "");
                    System.out.println(tempLine);
                    System.out.println(foodLine);
                    System.out.println(cleanLine);
```

Comment: The [continue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html_) statement might be what you're after.

Comment: @dave Sorry, clearly my question wasn't clear. Continue wouldn't have fixed the issue that I had. Especially considering I completely forgot to include a while statement... Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Describes using `break` statements with `labels` to break out of loops, this may be what you are referring to.

`break` is a keyword that exits a loop. `continue` is a keyword that exits an `iteration` of a loop, and uses the next element of the loop.

`break` is inside the if statement here, when true will exit the loop, and continue the program.

```
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfInts[i] == searchfor) {
            foundIt = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is most useful when dealing with nested loops, e.g.

in this example `search:` is a label preceeding the outer for loop, it can be used to say which loop you are attempting to break out of, otherwise break will default to the inner most loop.

```
search:
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
             j++) {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                foundIt = true;
                break search;
            }
        }
    }
```

it can also be used with `continue` which is referring to the outer loop, `label`ed `test`

```
test:
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        int n = substring.length();
        int j = i;
        int k = 0;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                continue test;
            }
        }
        foundIt = true;
            break test;
    }
    System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help.... I figured it out.

```
public class MonitoringSystem {


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inFS = null;
    FileInputStream animals = null;
    FileInputStream habitats = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String monitorChoice = "";
    String animalChoice = "";
    String habitatChoice = "";
    String userInput = "";


    while (!userInput.equals("exit")) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to monitor an Animal, Habitat, or exit?");
    monitorChoice = scnr.nextLine();


        if (monitorChoice.equals("Animal")) {
            System.out.println("Choose an animal to monitor: Lion, Tiger, Bear, or Giraffe.");
            animals = new FileInputStream("animals.txt");
            animalChoice = scnr.nextLine();
            File file = new File("animals.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String currentLine = br.readLine();
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentLine.contains(animalChoice)) {
                    String nameline = br.readLine();
                    String ageline = br.readLine();
                    String healthline = br.readLine();
                    String feedline = br.readLine();

                    healthline = healthline.replaceAll("[*]", "");
                    feedline = feedline.replaceAll("[*]", "");

                    System.out.println(currentLine);
                    System.out.println(nameline);
                    System.out.println(ageline);
                    System.out.println(feedline);
                    System.out.println(healthline);



                }
            }
        }
        else if (monitorChoice.equals("Habitat")) {
            System.out.println("Choose a habitat to monitor: Penguin, Bird, Aquarium.");
            habitats = new FileInputStream("habitats.txt");
            habitatChoice = scnr.nextLine();
            File habitat = new File("habitats.txt");
            BufferedReader bh = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(habitat));

            String habitatLine = bh.readLine();
            while ((habitatLine = bh.readLine()) != null) {
                if (habitatLine.contains(habitatChoice)) {
                    String tempLine = bh.readLine();
                    String foodLine = bh.readLine();
                    String cleanLine = bh.readLine();

                    foodLine = foodLine.replaceAll("[*]", "");
                    cleanLine = cleanLine.replaceAll("[*]", "");
                    System.out.println(tempLine);
                    System.out.println(foodLine);
                    System.out.println(cleanLine);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Have a great day!");
            break;
                }
         }
   }
```

}